# Difference between drawing on JPanel via paintComponent and Buffered Image

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

I have experimented with two different methods of drawing the same shape, the first image is drawn by overriding JPanel's paintComponent(Graphics g) method and using g.drawOval(..) etc,
The second image is drawn by creating a buffered image and drawing on it by using buffered image's graphics. How can I achieve the same rendering quality on both approaches? I have tried using many different rendering hints but none of them gave the same quality. I also tried sharpening by using Kernel and filtering, still couldn't.

```
private void createImage() {
        image = new BufferedImage(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();

        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        gr.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL, RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_PURE);
        //something along the way
        gr.drawOval(.....);
        gr.drawLine(.....);
        gr.drawOval(.....);

        panel.repaint();
        gr.dispose();
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(backgroundColor);
    if (USE_BUFFERED_IMAGE) {
        g.drawImage(image, startX, startY, null);
    } else {
        //something along the way
        g.drawOval(.....);
        g.drawLine(.....);
        g.drawOval(.....);
    }
}
```

[Drawing using JPanel paintComponent graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd6Tz.png)

[Drawing using Buffered Image graphics then it is drawn on Jpanel via drawimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZHlQ.png)

**EDIT**

I found my solution by getting almost every setting of panel graphics and applying them to buffered image graphics. Not by using only using the same rendering hints or "minimal reproducible examples" approaches. Here, the importing thing is that the panel's graphic scales everything by 1.25 and then scales down to the original before showing it on the panel.

Here is an example, -this is not exactly how my code is, this is just an example to give you an idea-

```
private void createImages(Paint paint, RenderingHints hints,
                         AffineTransform transform, Stroke stroke,
                        Composite composite, GraphicsConfiguration config ){

        image = config.createCompatibleImage(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
        // same options
        gr.setPaint(paint);
        gr.setRenderingHints(hints);
        gr.setTransform(transform);
        gr.setStroke(stroke);
        gr.setComposite(composite);

        //something along the way
        gr.drawOval(.....);
        gr.drawLine(.....);
        gr.drawOval(.....);

        panel.repaint();
        gr.dispose();
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(backgroundColor);
    if (USE_BUFFERED_IMAGE) {
       
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        createImages(g2.getPaint(), g2.getRenderingHints(),g2.getTransform(),
                     g2.getStroke(),g2.getComposite(), g2.getDeviceConfiguration());
         //scaling down is important because your drawings get scaled to 1.25
         // by panels graphics' transformation
         g.drawImage(image, startX, startY,(int)(IMG_SIZE*0.8),(int)(IMG_SIZE*0.8),  null);
    } else {
        //something along the way
        g.drawOval(.....);
        g.drawLine(.....);
        g.drawOval(.....);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't for the most part especially since the image is of a fixed size and when drawn inside your component whose size can vary based on its parent layout the image gets scaled which further degrades quality. One dumb idea you could try is draw each individual pixel of your image as an 1 x 1 rectangle with the specified pixel color inside your paint component. While terrible for performance if your image is static it might be worth it?

Comment: The preferred approach is to use the JPanel paintComponent method to draw on your GUI.  If you need a BufferedImage, you can create one using the JPanel printAll method.

Comment: *How can I achieve the same rendering quality on both approaches?* - Use the same rendering hints. For example, the paintComponent() method does not use anti aliasing by default. So the Graphics drawn to a BufferedImage will look different than the Graphics drawn in the paintComponent. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. Start by just drawing a single oval and get it working the same using both approaches. Then make the painting more complex. It is easier to debug this way. Also, don't change a property (background) of a component in that painting method.

Comment: "Use the same rendering hints" my problem is that I don't know what is the rendering hint is used in JPanel. Also, As I mentioned I have tried in many rendering hints, still couldn't achieve the same results.

Comment: PrintAll seems like a solution to my problem, I will update my message if I could manage what I am trying to do. I use buffered image to be able to drag the image around without rendering the complex drawing every time, which can take some time.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I have found my solution as I explained above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution by getting almost every setting of panel graphics and applying them to buffered image graphics. Here, the importing thing is that the panel's graphic scales everything by 1.25 and then scales down to the original before showing it on the panel.

Here is an example, -this is not exactly how my code is, this is just an example to give you an idea-

```
private void createImages(Paint paint, RenderingHints hints,
                         AffineTransform transform, Stroke stroke,
                        Composite composite, GraphicsConfiguration config ){

        image = config.createCompatibleImage(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
        // same options
        gr.setPaint(paint);
        gr.setRenderingHints(hints);
        gr.setTransform(transform);
        gr.setStroke(stroke);
        gr.setComposite(composite);

        //something along the way
        gr.drawOval(.....);
        gr.drawLine(.....);
        gr.drawOval(.....);

        panel.repaint();
        gr.dispose();
}



public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setBackground(backgroundColor);
    if (USE_BUFFERED_IMAGE) {
       
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        createImages(g2.getPaint(), g2.getRenderingHints(),g2.getTransform(),
                     g2.getStroke(),g2.getComposite(), g2.getDeviceConfiguration());
         //scaling down is important because your drawings get scaled to 1.25
         // by panels graphics' transformation
         g.drawImage(image, startX, startY,(int)(IMG_SIZE*0.8),(int)(IMG_SIZE*0.8),  null);
    } else {
        //something along the way
        g.drawOval(.....);
        g.drawLine(.....);
        g.drawOval(.....);
    }
}
```